# How to get sar command value in 24 hour format (from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59) in Linux?

Tags: linux, time

I want to generate a file which has `cpu usage` logs in 24 hour format (from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59`). I am using `sar` command but it gives time in AM or PM format which is not required.

Sample:

```
12:01:01 AM     all      1.33      0.00      1.06      0.24      0.00     97.37
12:02:01 AM     all      1.30      0.00      1.02      0.04      0.00     97.64
```

Expected result:

```
00:01:01 all      1.33      0.00      1.06      0.24      0.00     97.37
00:02:01 all      1.30      0.00      1.02      0.04      0.00     97.64
```

Answer (score 15):

The `sar` program is a so-called *locale aware program*. Meaning it's output format is controlled by the `LC_*` environment variables. The variable `LC_TIME` is responsible for the output of time data. (see `man locale`).

Looks like you are using a system where `LC_TIME` is set to `en_US` - a locale using the `12hours AM/PM format` (or `LC_TIME` was kept empty which will lead to using the default locale). You need to use a locale setting which is using the 24 hour format. Lets say `en_UK`. You can specify it on the command line:

```
LC_TIME=en_UK.utf8 sar
```

**Output:**

```
Linux 3.13.0-44-generic (desktop1)  01/22/15    _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

00:00:01        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
00:02:01        all      2,26      0,00      0,41      0,71      0,00     96,63
00:04:01        all      2,68      0,00      0,72      0,46      0,00     96,13
...
```

---

Note! If the locale `en_UK.uft8` isn't available on your system, you need to generate it using:

```
sudo locale-gen en_UK.utf8
```

or you can use `POSIX` or `C`:

```
LC_TIME='POSIX' sar
LC_TIME='C' sar
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you already have a `sarNN` file from another machine, this `sed` command comes at handy:

```
sed -r --in-place=.bak \
  's/([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} (AM|PM))(.*)/echo $(date --date="\1" +%T) "\3"/e' \
  sar_with_wrong_date_format
```

It's relatively slow, because it runs `date` in a subshell for each line, but compensates with clarity of the intent, and still does the job in several seconds.